# Gensim tfidf vector in dense form

Tags: gensim

I am vectorizing a bunch of documents using Gensim's `tfidfmodel`. I'd like to take the output so I can dump it into a vector DB and calculate document similarity using the DB. (I'm aware Gensim has the `similarities` module but would like to do this within a DB.)

Using the [example from the docs](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/auto_examples/core/run_topics_and_transformations.html), here is a sample output:

```
dictionary = corpora.Dictionary(texts)
corpus = [dictionary.doc2bow(text) for text in texts]
tfidf = models.TfidfModel(corpus)
corpus_tfidf = tfidf[corpus]

for doc in corpus_tfidf:
  print(doc)

[(0, 0.5773502691896257), (1, 0.5773502691896257), (2, 0.5773502691896257)]
[(0, 0.44424552527467476), (3, 0.44424552527467476), (4, 0.44424552527467476), (5, 0.3244870206138555), (6, 0.44424552527467476), (7, 0.3244870206138555)]
[(2, 0.5710059809418182), (5, 0.4170757362022777), (7, 0.4170757362022777), (8, 0.5710059809418182)]
[(1, 0.49182558987264147), (5, 0.7184811607083769), (8, 0.49182558987264147)]
[(3, 0.6282580468670046), (6, 0.6282580468670046), (7, 0.45889394536615247)]
[(9, 1.0)]
[(9, 0.7071067811865475), (10, 0.7071067811865475)]
[(9, 0.5080429008916749), (10, 0.5080429008916749), (11, 0.695546419520037)]
[(4, 0.6282580468670046), (10, 0.45889394536615247), (11, 0.6282580468670046)]
```

Am I correct in thinking that I need to convert each document array to a dense array? My assumption is that I cannot take the second element in each tuple of the doc array since the document array omits vocab not present. How do I convert this to a dense array?

Is `matutils.corpus2dense(corpus_tfidf,dictionary.num_nnz).T` the correct approach?

```
import gensim.matutils
densematrix = gensim.matutils.corpus2dense(corpus_tfidf,dictionary.num_nnz).T
```

Comment: Which vector DB are you using? What does it require as the format of stored vectors? What happens when you tried putting the `densmatrix` from you candidate approach into your particular vector DB?

Comment: Notably: I believe many such DBs often used with vectors that are both 'dense' in their underlying implementation, & their typical values – where most/all dimensions non-zero, but with far fewer dimensions in total than sparse/few-hot representations. That is: hundreds of 'dense embedding' dimensions, rather than tens-of-thousands to hundreds-of-thousands of mostly-zero dimensions. So beware that in seeking to load sparse very-large-number-of-dimension vectors into some vector DBs, you may be outside of typical use & experience quite a bit of extra representational overhead.

Comment: I was looking into both Milvus and [ES](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dense-vector.html).


Can you explain your second comment a bit more? Are you saying that many of these so called vector DBs tend to store in dense formats, and the performance implication thereof makes them unsuitable for for large sparse datasets? If so, what is the generally accepted way of storing this type of information?

Comment: What happens when you tried putting the `densematrix` representations from you candidate approach into your particular vector DB? Was there an error or did it work? Was behavior as expected, or were there issues (like perhaps the stored representation expanding a lot)? Are you hitting any blocking problem here, and if so, what? Whether a particular vector DB is optimized for dense or sparse storage, or other operations, would be specific to that DB, and not being familiar with ither Milvus or ES, I don't know their specialties.

Comment: But I see the ES page you link only mentions dense vectors, & the Milvus homepage touts similarity search – whose optimal bulk performance likely requires non-sparse at-rest representations. (A query engine wouldn't want to de-densify a compressed sparse representation *every* time a similarity-search is attempted.) Hence, the best answer to what happens if you stuff your sprase vectors into a candidate vector DB is to actually try stuffing your sparse vectors into your candidate vector DB, & observe what works, or doesn't.

Comment: Your comments make sense, thank you. I have yet to actually put these into the DB at scale, as I was seeking confirmation on how to get a dense representation out of Gensim. I _think_ `corpus2dense` is the right thing to do, but could you confirm? Thanks!

Comment: And to clarify, I will try both dense and sparse!

Comment: `corpus2dense` looks like a plausible thing to me, but whether your vector DB takes what it returns is best tested by trying it! I'd be wary of potential large expansion in representation overhead, if converting a large corpus all at once. And note that per the docs, documents become columns rather than rows.